# CURL precision on windows

Tags: python, windows, curl, libcurl

Within windows pycurl gives a precision of timings to 3 decimal places, is there a way to improve this to something much more precise?

```
> print c.getinfo(pycurl.CONNECT_TIME)
> 0.265
```

Linux for example gives it to approx 7 decimal places.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Looking at the source for pycurl, it's just calling the underlying cURL function:

```
case CURLINFO_CONNECT_TIME: // other cases [snip]ped
        /* Return PyFloat as result */
        double d_res = 0.0;

        res = curl_easy_getinfo(self->handle, (CURLINFO)option, &d_res);
        if (res != CURLE_OK) {
            CURLERROR_RETVAL();
        }
        return PyFloat_FromDouble(d_res);
    }
```

which in turn does

```
case CURLINFO_CONNECT_TIME:
    *param_doublep = data->progress.t_connect;
    break;
```

and `t_connect` is assigned by

```
data->progress.t_connect = Curl_tvdiff_secs(now, data->progress.t_startsingle);
```

which references `t_startsingle`, which is assigned by `Curl_tvnow`, which is under Windows defined to be

```
struct timeval curlx_tvnow(void)
{
  /*
  ** GetTickCount() is available on _all_ Windows versions from W95 up
  ** to nowadays. Returns milliseconds elapsed since last system boot,
  ** increases monotonically and wraps once 49.7 days have elapsed.
  */
  struct timeval now;
  DWORD milliseconds = GetTickCount();
  now.tv_sec = milliseconds / 1000;
  now.tv_usec = (milliseconds % 1000) * 1000;
  return now;
}
```

That is, millisecond precision.

So short of patching and recompiling cURL to use a higher precision timer, then compiling pyCURL against that, no. Sorry!

Answer (score 2):

I'm afraid this is a limitation in the underlying libcurl code. It uses the GetTickCount() function call in Windows, which is [documented like this](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms724408%28v=vs.85%29.aspx):

> The resolution of the GetTickCount function is limited to the
>   resolution of the system timer, which is typically in the range of 10
>   milliseconds to 16 milliseconds.